# How do I send information to Twilio Autopilot for use by the bot?

Tags: twilio

I've created a simple bot that uses a chat channel.  I'd like to pass the end user's ID and the page ID to autopilot when the bot is initiated.   Ultimately, this will help me ensure that I handoff the user to the correct worker.

I can't seem to find any information on this, but perhaps I am overthinking it?

Comment: I was definitely overthinking it.   The short version is that I didn't send anything to the chatbot (yet), I'm just using webhooks to combine chatbot data with my app data.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

This is a feature gap the Autopilot product team is aiming to fill before the end of the year.

Hope this helps!